# Problems with Forms, using POST method with Mechanize in Python

Tags: python, forms, post, radio-button, mechanize

I was trying to fill a form using mechanize in python, it didn't work with normal submit(). Somehow mechanize didn't manage to parse the radio buttons and found only 1 instead of 4. After that I tried to write a POST request -

```
    data = {
        'localid' : '11755',
        'language' : '3',
        'code' : 'hello world',
    }
    page = browser.open( self.submiturl, urllib.urlencode( data) )
```

But it doesn't post anyhing at all. I am not sure what I am missing here, is it the right way make a POST? Is there any other way to make mechanize recognize radio buttons?

My full code can be read from [this link](http://ideone.com/kSq97).

Comment: Have you tried to check whether created url is correct or not? Try the following links: http://nullege.com/codes/search/mechanize.Browser.open and/or http://nullege.com/codes/search/mechanize.urljoin to get more info

Comment: I think the url is correct. And I am not using GET, I am using POST. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like mechanize is having trouble parsing the form, try something along these lines

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
resp = br.open('your_url_here')
print resp.get_data() # if you want to see what's returned
# if you want to see the forms, so you can find the index of the
# form you want and check that is has all the fields, if it doesn't
# you should should parse the response with BeautifulSoup
for form in br.forms():
    print '---------------'
    print form
br.select_form(nr=0) # to select the first form
br['field_name'] = 'field_value'
br['select_field_name'] = ['select_field_value']
br.submit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. It parsed the radio-buttons correctly once I wrote used your way.